# How to convert int to little endian hex

Tags: java

In java I need to write message length to tcp header,

for input 474 (which is 1DA in hex) i need to convert it to DA01 as little endian order.I have tried as follows but didn't work.

```
    ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.put(Integer.toHexString(474).getBytes());
    byte[] result=buffer.array();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

result is [49, 100, 97, 0] at this point.

Comment: why `toHexString()`? try `buffer.putInt(474)` and `String.format("%02X%02X", result[0], result[1])` (and you could do that without `ByteBuffer`

Comment: I tried already it doesnt work.For putInt result is 000001da as Hex

Comment: without  ByteBuffer: `String.format("%02X%02X", 474 & 0xFF, 474 >> 8 & 0xFF)` or even `String.format("%02X%02X", (byte) 474, (byte) (474>>8))`